# Improving a Tumbleweed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I posted the question "[Security door with lock guard](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147081/security-door-with-lock-guard)" last week and today it earned the Tumbleweed badge. I tried to be as clear as I could, but it's difficult when I don't know the name of what I'm trying to describe. Is there anything that can be done to improve my question and make it more answerable here? Would this be better on a different SE site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the choice of site is fine (locks in general are fine on DIY), but maybe you should offer a bounty on the question. We don't get a lot of those and that should help you get an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the bounty a try. I had thought about that but hesitated because I would drop below the Association Bonus, but it looks like I wouldn't lose any major privileges.